# Ajax mysql insert not working

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

I have the following Javascript code triggered after a game action in order to save current score to a DB using ajax:

```
            $(oMain).on("save_score", function(evt,iMoney) {

               //  alert ('you won: $'+iMoney);

                 $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: 'write.php',
                 data: ({prize:iMoney}),
                 success: function(data) {
                 alert(data);
                 }
             });

             });
```

and i have the write.php file writing to the DB :

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "admin";
$dbname = "games";

$prize=$_POST['prize'];

$query="INSERT INTO game_result (user_, amount)
        VALUES('user','$prize')";
$con =  new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);

$qry_result = $con->query($query);
?>
```

nevertheless Nothing happens on db side and ajax returns an empty string. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: mind removing the CAPS from the title please? or use Camel Case

Comment: You PHP script right now returns nothing. In the future you can check the "network" tab in the developer tools in your browser to see if the POST request is fired with the right data and if it returns anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii- done caps removed